# How can I set reference of a Domain class from inside itself in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Here I am facing an unusual issue. Everything should work in my understanding (as a grails beginner), but not working :(

I have a domain class User. User can have many friends and many friendRequests. There is a function in domain class to send friend request to other user. here is the code from User Domain -

```
static hasMany = [friends: User, friendRequests: FriendRequest]
static mappedBy = [friendRequests:'receiver']

def sendFriendRequest(User toUser) {

    if(!isFriend(toUser)) {
        FriendRequest requestToSend = new FriendRequest(status:'pending', sender: this) 
        toUser.addToFriendRequests(requestToSend)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

And the FriendRequest class is -

```
class FriendRequest {

    String status
    User sender

    static constraints = {
    status(inList:["accepted", "pending", "rejected"])
    }

    static belongsTo = [receiver:User]
}
```

Now, The problem is, I am expecting the current User object, from which I am running the function will be set as sender of friendRequest. But strangely the toUser, which I m passing as param is being set as sender!

Can anyone please explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addToFriendRequests` method is overriding sender.  It thinks that `FriendRequest.sender` is the inverse of `User.friendRequests`

Your `FriendRequest` class will need two references to `User`: one for the sender, and one for the receiver.  You'll also need to tell gorm which one maps back to the `friendRequests` relationship.  You can do this with a mapping in your `User` class:

```
static mappedBy = [friendRequests:'receiver']
```

Comment: It it just me or does that feel messed up?

Comment: It helps to think about how the relationships are represented in a database.  The FriendRequest needs to have a reference to the User's id, to support having multiple friend requests per User.  The general rule is the "many" side keeps a reference to the "one" side.  The `hasMany` map says what class links to User, but it doesn't say where to store that reference.  Grails just picks a reasonable default, the first User in FriendRequest.

Comment: Hello ataylor, Thanks a lot for quick response. Yes I already did this mapping as `static mappedBy = [friendRequests:'receiver']` And adding friendRequest class in question.